# Determine when computer woke up from hibernate?

Tags: windows-7, logging, hibernate, timestamp

How do I determine at what time the computer woke up from hibernate?

Answer (score -1):

You should install Windows Performance Tools Kit as detailed here http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=146919.

Then `xbootmgr -trace hibernate -traceFlags BASE+CSWITCH+DRIVERS+POWER -resultPath C:\TEMP` from a command prompt with admin rights.

Solution from http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140247-trace-windows-7-bootshutdownhibernatestandbyresume-issues/

I am going to downvote this question because the link I provided was the first result from a google search: http://bit.ly/1i6COJb

Comment: 1. Sometimes part of the solution is to know the right phrase to search on google. I've searched with different phrases and couldn't find a solution. Anyway, thank you for posting an answer 2. As far as I understand this solution won't work if user hibernated normally (from start menu and not by this xbootmgr command line)